# window.onscroll Bugando animação

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma animação onde quando o TOP > 2800 a animação vai começar.
A animação vai fazer os numeros dentro de um UL LI aumentarem do 0 até o numero escrito.

BUG:
O numero as vezes sobe todo e aparece outro, ou aumenta só um pouco e quando você mexe a tela ele vai aumentando pouco a pouco.

```
    window.onscroll = function(){
   var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
   if( top > 2800 ) {
  $('.spincrement').spincrement({
    from: 0,
    decimalPlaces:0 ,
    duration: 4000,
  });
   }

};
```

Comment: Coloca o teu javascript junto com um HTML fictício em um codepen ou em um JSFiddle, por favor.

Comment: você pode ver aqui amigo http://somospixel.com/test  em baixo do NOSSOS PROJETOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEU CERTO DA SEGUINTE FORMA.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

var trava = false;
window.onscroll = function(){
   var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
   if( top > 2800 && !trava) {
      trava = true;
      $('.spincrement').spincrement({
         from: 0,
         decimalPlaces:0 ,
         duration: 4000,
         complete: function() { trava = true; }
      });
   }
};          
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

como você sabe, o evento window.onscroll é disparado quando há evento de rolagem da barra de scroll, input no teclado para rolagem do scroll, assim como o mouse. Portanto, o cenário do bug que você descreveu é o certo pelo código que você mostrou, isso porque quando você dispara a sua função de animação, o evento window.onscroll ainda é disparado. Portanto, ele só é incrementado de pouco em pouco, ou seja, quando há mudança no scroll. Cenário:

top = 2801 -> dispara sua animação e para;
top = 2802 -> ocorre mais um evento scroll...volta a ação de incrementar do zero

Isso deve está ocasionando tal comportamento. Eu entendi que ao chegar ao 2801 você quer que a animação comece e o evento onscroll pare e a animação ocorra e termine a animação? Apenas uma vez, certo? Se sim, então é preciso modificar o código para que ele ocorra apenas uma vez. Uma variável de controle ou event.preventDefault() podem te ajudar.